# PostgreSQL: Which hardware (number of cores, RAM, storage type, storage size) and what number of hosts are needed?

Tags: postgresql, performance, performance-tuning

There is a Log DB. As I understand, there are two constraints which influence the answer to my question: space needed to store the database, number of reads-writes/sec needed.

There are 72 M records inserted per day, which is equivalent to 2000 records generated per second during 10 active hours. There is no limitation on number of client threads that need to do inserts. It can be hundreds of clients.
We need to store 180 days of this information like a sliding window - 13 000 M records in total, 30 TB (2500 bytes per record).
When a new day starts, data for the oldest day shall be removed;

In parallel some subsystem periodically queries this DB with 500 reads/sec, there is no limitation on number of threads for that, it can be tens of threads:

```
select * from T_LOG_RECORD
where
    ((F_EXTERNAL_ID="92" AND F_SCOPE="CONT") OR F_GROUP_TAG="100000164")
    AND F_RECORD_TIME < "2016-12-12 23:59:59" 
    AND "2016-11-12 00:00:00" < F_RECORD_TIME AND F_STATUS = 0
```

Here is the draft DDL (Oracle syntax) of the single table in this DB to understand the idea, indexes are skipped:

```
CREATE TABLE T_LOG_RECORD (
    T_LOG_RECORD NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
    F_NOTIFICATION_ID VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    T_OPERATOR_ID NUMBER(20) NULL,
    T_LANGUAGE_ID NUMBER(2),
    F_RECORD_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    F_ADDRESS_TYPE NUMBER(2) NULL,
    F_ADDRESS_VALUE VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    F_EXTERNAL_ID VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    F_SCOPE VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    F_SUBJECT VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    F_TEMPLATE_ID NUMBER(20) NULL,
    F_MESSAGE_TEMPLATE CLOB NULL,
    F_MESSAGE CLOB NULL,
    F_NOTIFICATION_PARAMS CLOB NULL,
    F_TRIGGERED_TIME TIMESTAMP(0) NULL,
    F_EXPIRED_TIME TIMESTAMP(0) NULL,
    F_GROUP_TAG VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    F_STATUS NUMBER(2) NOT NULL,
    F_DISCARD_REASON NUMBER(2) NULL,
    F_PRIORITY NUMBER(2) NULL,
    F_ERROR_CODE VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    F_DELIVERY_TIME TIMESTAMP(8) NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (F_RECORD_TIME)
    INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(1, 'DAY'))
    (PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('08-01-2017', 'DD-MM-YYYY')))
    TABLESPACE SOME_TABLESPACE
;
```

I assume that commodity server hardware will be used. We will implement sharding on application level, with active-standby replication with 1 redundant copy.

My current assumption is that PostgreSQL on a single host (8 cores, 64 GB RAM, 2 x 4 TB SSD without any RAID) will be able to handle 10 K inserts/sec/host.
So we will need 8 hosts/VMs with such parameters. The calculation is the following:
30 TB * 2 (replication factor) / 8 TB (total disk size on host) = 8 hosts.
So there will be 4 host-shards and 4 hosts-replicas. Inserts will be done on host-shards, selects will be done on all hosts (shards and replicas).

Is my calculation correct?

Comment: One thing you should note first, is how this data will be written. Is there any parallelism? How will your application work with the PostgreSQL? How many concurrent users? Because 1 user inserting 2000 lines needs an X hardware, but 100 users inserting 2000 lines is Y. You can use SQLBenchmark [1] to benchmark your environment. I've seen environments with 8k inserts / sec, 1 host only, used lots of CPU, almost no memory, and MUCH disk. I would tell you to test, and test a lot, not to spend what you do not need, or not to have surprises. 1- https://sourceforge.net/projects/benchmarksql

Comment: No amount of theoretical calculations will replace proper capacity testing.

Comment: you'll get faster read and write performance for less money using 8x1 TB drives in RAID 10

Comment: @mustaccio I agree, but since DB size and TPS are quite big, I hope to learn some experience of people with similar challenge.

Comment: @Neil McGuigan, but with 8x1 TB drives in RAID 10 I will get only 4 TB of space

Comment: thanks for answers. I've corrected my post: there is no limitation on client side for the number of threads which are doing inserts and selects. It can be hundreds of threads.
Do you have links to benchmarksql results on big number of records for SSD?

Comment: @Neighbour I assumed your "2 x 4 TB SSD" would be in RAID 1 for redundancy, which would give you 4 TB of space (per machine)

Comment: Unfortunately there is no, one kb with with results. But that result that I mentioned above, is the tests that I performed in my monograph. I can translate for you some results that I have obtained on which scenario.

Comment: "active-standby replication with 1 redundant copy" is not a substitute for RAID on each node. RAID5 over 5 2TB SSDs will give you 8TB and fits nicely in 1U with space for boot disks etc.

Comment: What is the distribution of the "500 reads/sec" queries, are they evenly spread out over the whole data set?

Comment: @Jack Douglas, yes, 500 reads/sec query different data from the whole data set, so the taken data are evenly spread.

Comment: OK — I didn't notice the date on this Q was Jan 2017 not Jan 2018, so presumably you have hindsight on all of this. Your answer means I understand the use of SSD as the read IO is scattered and you won't be able to have a memory cache big enough to buffer what you need. Did you implement what you were planning?

Comment: @Jack Douglas No, I didn't implement, because this project is still on hold.